# Can different websites hosted at different providers use the same domain, safe for the subdomain?

Tags: subdomain

My client has a domain (let's say `www.clientdomain.com`) which is linked to a Woocommerce store hosted at GoDaddy.

I'm currently deploying an application consisting on a Flask API and a React SPA. The Flask API will be hosted at PythonAnywhere, while the React SPA is deployed at Firebase hosting.

Can I use `www.clientdomain.com/<api_name>` as the domain for the API, and `www.clientdomain/<frontend_application>` even although the root domain (`www.clientdomain.com`) directs to a different application at a different hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a subdomain of your client's domain (e.g. **api.clientdomain.com**) for your Flask API, and another subdomain (e.g. **frontend.clientdomain.com**) for your React SPA. This is possible because subdomains are treated as separate domains, even though they are part of the main domain.

Keep in mind that we are speaking about **subdomains**, `www.clientdomain.com/<api_name>` and `www.clientdomain.com/<frontend_application>` are directory of the main domain, they aren't subdomains

To use a subdomain for your Flask API, you will need to **create a subdomain in your domain's DNS settings**, and then **point that subdomain to the IP address of your PythonAnywhere server**. You can then configure your Flask API to be accessible at that subdomain.

Similarly, you can create another subdomain for your React SPA and point it to the IP address of your Firebase hosting server. This will allow you to access your React SPA at that subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host your Flask Api on your subdomain, it will be something like flask.yourdomain.com. It won't impact anything to your main site.